# IN operator query fail in php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am passing array in query to fetch the results.I am using IN operator of SQL for this purpose.As per SQL syntax it should be **IN('value1','Value2');**. I am using following code create & execute query.

```
   $categories=array();
    $categories=$_GET['category'];


$query = 'SELECT * from postdata Where category IN (" . implode(',', $categories) . ")';

echo $query;

$run = mysql_query($query);
if(!$run)
{
echo "query failed";
echo mysql_error();
}
else
{
echo "not failed";
}
```

My query print like this.

```
SELECT * from postdata Where category IN (Activated)
```

No quotes for inside IN in query is this reason my query fails?

Comment: Yes. Best to use prepared statements.

Comment: *"No quotes for inside IN in query is this reason my query fails?"* - Yepper pepper!

Comment: How can put a php variable inside a quote .I tried like this '.$name.' but it printed $name how can prit it's value like 'activated'

Comment: `"'" . implode("', '", $categories) . "'"`. This is susceptible to SQL injection.

Comment: Find a proper library or query builder which utilizes a modern database API and provides convenience functions such as `db("... WHERE x IN (??)", $array)` for you.